# can some one give some samples or resource above stagefright?

Tags: stream, stagefright

I am studying android recently,I want to decode TS stream with stagefright and want to know how stagefright deal with video file or stream,but I know little about stagefright.can some one give some samples ,project or resource above stagefright ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line utility to decode the `TS` file, sources of which can be found at [`frameworks\av\cmds`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp). The sources of the `TSExtractor` can be found at [`mpeg2ts`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/mpeg2ts/). I presume this should enable you to experiment and study the code.